# Simple WSOESB Proxy doen't response

Tags: wso2-esb

Very simple example. Request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <T>
      <m1>bysy</m1>
      <m1>momo</m1>
      <m1>gigi</m1>
    </T>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I want to iterate and log every element in tag m1.

Proxy code:

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="Loopback" transports="https,http"
  <target>
    <inSequence>
      <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
      <iterate expression="//T/m1">
        <target>
           <sequence>
              <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
              <log level="custom">
                 <property name="M1" expression="//text()"/>
              </log>
              <drop/>
           </sequence>
        </target>
      </iterate>
    </inSequence>
  </target>
</proxy>
```

It work as expected and logs all values. But WSO2ESB server doesn't close connection, until it falls with timeout.  (I use SOAPUI for testing)

I tried to put properties OUT_ONLY RESPOND NO_KEEPALIVE in different part of proxy but it didn't help, as well I tried to use ,  with same result.

It looks like problem in *iterate* mediator which doesn't let to inSequence to terminate and send response to client. Once i remove it, proxy disconnect immediately with status code '202' *message accepted*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because, by default, attribute "continueParent" is set to false with iterate mediator : change to `<iterate continueParent="true" expression="//T/m1">`

And you should explicitly send a 202 inside your inSequence, set this property : `<property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" value="true" scope="axis2"/>`

Comment: Is this correct? Parent sequence is terminated  due default attribute "continueParent", and there are another two sequences are lauched, execute "log" mediator and terminate. If there is a way to provide some response to client from those new sequences?

Comment: There is one IN sequence flow, starting in the inSequence of your proxy. with the iterate, there is a fork and sub-sequences are executed to process xml fragments. If continueParent is false, mediators that appears after the iterate are not executed. If continueParent is true, they are executed (and can be executed concurently with the mediatiors inside the iterate's sequence). Within a IN flow, you can only send back one response so, you musn't send a response from the iterate's sequence : use continueParent or use clone mediator before iterate